# How to stop main method calling sleep() method, when testing it with Junit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, thread-sleep

I am testing a method which contain sleep in side it.What is the way to stop invoke sleep() as it makes testing slow??

```
  public void fun(Integer timeToWait) {
    TimeLimiter timeLimiter = new SimpleTimeLimiter();
    try {
      timeLimiter.callWithTimeout(() -> {
        while (true) {
          if (avrageIsAboveThanDesired) {
            return true;
          }
          sleep(ofSeconds(REQUEST_STATUS_CHECK_INTERVAL));
        }
      }, timeToWait, TimeUnit.MINUTES, true);
    } catch (UncheckedTimeoutException e) {
      logger.error("Timed out waiting Instances to be in Running State", e);
    } catch (WingsException e) {
      throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new InvalidRequestException("Error while waiting Instaces to be in Running State", e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Calling such "low level" methods like sleep() is a problem in itself. See https://medium.com/my-random-thoughts-in-software-engineering/get-rid-of-thread-sleep-e2abf3cadb6 for example. Meaning: dont just go and pick the first utility class that sounds helpful (like guavas TimeLimiter). Rather understand what these things are doing ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no easy way for doing this. You have several options.

The easiest one would be to make the `REQUEST_STATUS_CHECK_INTERVAL` configurable and configure it to `0` in tests. It can be a property of the tested class.

```
sleep(ofSeconds(getSleepInternval()));
```

In the test would wold call

```
testedObject.setSleepInterval(0);
```

Second option would be to extract the sleep call into it's own class that can be mocked.

```
class Sleeper {
   void sleep(long milisecs) {
     Thread.sleep(milisecs);
   }
}
```

In your class you would have

```
private Sleeper sleeper = new Sleeper(); //nd it's setter, or dependency injection
```

In the function

```
sleeper.sleep(ofSeconds(REQUEST_STATUS_CHECK_INTERVAL));
```

And it the test you can do

```
Sleeper mockedSleeper = Mockito.mock(Sleeper.class);
testedObject.setSleeper(mockedSleeper);
```

Comment: Good point, but adding a setter() is always a bad choice (because that prevents you from making the field final). So: one could either use Mockitos @ InjectMocks annotation ... or add a constructor that takes the required objects, to allow for "manual" injection.